# html-loader doesn't work even though webpack.config.js is configured

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I use `require("./about.html")`, then I get this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file.

I have installed html-loader, and have set up my **webpack.config.js** file, but I don't know why I'm still getting this error. Here is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
        options: {
          minimize: true,
        }
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

Instead of having the webpack.config file in the root directory, I can change my webpack configurations using **react-app-rewired**.

Further information here: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

Then, in the config-overrides.js file, I made these changes:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...
  
  let RuleToAdd = {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: "html-loader",
    options: {minimize: true}
  };
  config.module.rules.push(RuleToAdd);

  return config;
}
```

Now, using `require("./about.html")` works fine.